# Please let me know how to use the MS Access query in form of Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I just need your suggestion like how to use the SQL queries of MS Access in forms of MS Access as I have some several queries which i need to use and develop some forms. So, i want to know how to use the queries of MS Access in form wizard of MS Access and please let me know if there is any limitations in using the queries in form wizard.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Go to the **property sheet** of a form.

2.Then go to the **Data** tab.

3.Then choose a **record source**

4.Create a **textbox** in the Form

5.Go to the **property sheet** of the textbox

6.Go to the **data** tab.

7.Click the **control source** drop down and select the field from the query you want

According to your example the control source drop down should contain two fields, area and multiplication

Comment: hello i know the thing from record source but i want to know whether can I use my exact query in the form??? like if i have 4 rows (ID,Colum1,Column2,column3) and i want to do some substration between 'column1 rows' and i generated a new column with that substraction values like new 'column 4' and i developed it with a query. Now i want to add this query in my form the query that i  wrote is a sample i have lot complex queries. The purpose is like i want to develop a tool which involves lot of matematical calculations and lot of queries.If you know about this problem please let me know

Comment: That is still a bit unclear, are you saying you want to do subtraction within the query or do two separate queries with the 2nd one using the first one?

Comment: I have developed a query and it is working fine i want to add the exact query in a MS ACCESS form is it possible or not ??

Comment: You have a query and you want to add it to a form. The above answer makes the query a source for the form, and then you can distribute it to text boxes, or other holders inside the form.

Comment: ok thank you but how can i distribute a query data into text boxes becuase a query is filled with different data from different tables and we will be performing variety of opertaions using them.can i know how can i distribute with a small example query if possible.

Comment: consider this example                                               SELECT 
   calculation_w.area,
   calculation_w.Dimentions * calculation_l.Dimentions AS miltiplication
FROM  
calculation AS calculation_w INNER JOIN
calculation AS calculation_l ON (calculation_w.[Length/width] = 'w' AND calculation_l.

[Length/width] = 'l' AND calculation_w.area = calculation_l.area)

Comment: One quick question: is this going to be the source for your form?

Comment: ya i use this query in the form that is why i need to know whether i can use this type of queries in forms or not ??